# Pulling JSON data from API server in Angular 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Struggling to get http:get to pull a request from a API server in an Ionic app, can anyone help with the code. Here is what I have:

```
    <form ng-submit="getOrders()">
        <label class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
          <span class="input-label">Search Order #</span>
          <input type="text" name="order number" placeholder="enter order number" ng-model="query">
         </label>
         <input class="button button-block button-positive" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">                    
    </form>

    $scope.getOrders= function(){
                 $http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/orders/'+ $scope.query).success(function(data) {
                  $scope.orders = [ data.data ];
                  $scope.query = query;
                  console.log(query);

                 })
              }
```

Here are a few http get code blocks I have tried without success

```
    //$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/').success(function(data) {
    //$http({ url: 'http://example.com/api/booking/orders/', method: "GET", params: {query} }).success(function(data) {
    //$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/+ $scope.query').success(function(data) {
    //$http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/get/orders/121137').success(function(data) {
    //$http.get('js/121137.json').success(function(data) {
```

[image: Search box]

Also, here is an example of some working POST code to an API which may provide some extra clues in performing a successful GET query from an API server:
https://plnkr.co/edit/w0cyfzGij8SgcsnbXqsj?p=catalogue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use promise as follows

```
.then(function(success){
 //handle success
 })
.catch(function(error){
//handle error
})
```

Answer (score 0):

this is currect code.

```
$scope.getOrders= function(){
                 $http.get('http://example.com/api/booking/orders/'+$scope.query).success(function(data) {
                  $scope.orders = data.data;
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log($scope.query);

                 })
              }
```

Comment: Nope, this doesn't work I'm afraid. Just wondering whether it is a problem with my form/function